# Mathematica empty plot

Tags: education

Function:

`F[t_] := 0.78540 - 0.63662 cos (2 t) - 0.07074 cos (6 t) -  0.02546 cos (10 t) - 0.01299 cos (14 t)`

Plot command: `Plot[F[t], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},  Ticks -> {{-\[Pi], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, Automatic},  PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Blue]`

Problem: empty plot output

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `cos (2 t)` is not a valid command in Mathematica. Whenever something is shown as blue in Mathematica, that means it is a symbol that has no definition. Also, every built-in function in Mathematica begins with a capital (which is why it's best to start your own functions with a lower-case letter, particularly since there are 1-letter symbols with pre-defined meaning such as `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, `K`, `O`, and `N`) and functions require square brackets. You probably want `Cos[2 t]`.

Comment: It worked! thanks so much for the help